# How to embed "large text" and "equations" in a GUI using Qt designer?

Tags: python, qt, qt-designer

I am trying to design a simple GUI using Qt Designer (with python).

I have already created two 'tabs' (pages), in the first tab a user can input variables and get let's say a calculated result. In the second tab, I would like to display a text document and equations which supplement the background info for the calculation performed in the first tab. How can I do this from Qt Designer?

For short/one line texts, it is possible to use one of the 'display widgets'. But my problem is with 'lager texts' and 'equation'.

Comment: please show us what u have done...

Comment: You'd probably want to use `QTextBrowser`, and write code to generate the background information using the html subset supported by Qt. Equations would have to be rendered into images. You could also render it into html/mathjax and use a web view to render it. The choice really is yours, but there's nothing in Designer itself that has much to do with your content: you'll have to generate it programmatically.

Comment: Thank you! QTextBrowser works fine for me.